# Can I claim child care expenses as a deduction on my federal return in Quebec?

Tags: canada, income-tax, tax-credit, child-care, quebec

My friend want to claim Child Care expense for Federal Tax, but as she lived in Quebec, a large part of her children's day care fees are already returned by Quebec government.  So could she still claim Child Care expense in Federal Tax return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [here](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/ncm-tx/rtrn/cmpltng/ddctns/lns206-236/214/menu-eng.html), but that material suggests that the answer is "no," at least for the reimbursed part.

Comment: I found this "You can claim payments for child care expenses that you paid for the parental contribution set ($7.00 per day) by the government of Québec." Real confusing. Can you explain a bit?

Comment: @Peter They're saying you can claim amounts you paid and were not reimbursed for.  You can't claim the part of the expenses that are covered by the Québec government.  Example: If total child care expenses were $2000 but the province covered $1400, then you could claim only $600 on your federal return for the child care expenses.  i.e. one's own out-of-pocket expenses.